# How to replace a NULL value based on a condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to replace a null value with a value that derives from a condition?
I have the following table in Oracle (left side):

[image]

I want to replace the NULL value in the manager column with the name of the Manager that has the highest Sales. I don't really care about the Sales column. It can stay as a NULL. To the right side of the picture attached you can see the desired result. I should mention that all I care about is the last green row, therefore if the rest of the information have to go that's totally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using analytic functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(manager,
                first_value(manager ignore nulls) over (order by sales desc)
               ) as imputed_manager
from t;
```

If you actually want this in an update, then:

```
update t
    set manager = (select max(manager) keep (dense_rank first order by sales desc nulls last)
                   from t
                   where manager is not null
                  )
    where manager is null;
```

I don't like changing the data directly like this.  It seems dangerous.

Comment: The `update` won't work as written. By default, when you order by sales **desc**, nulls will be first; in the OP's example, then, `max(manager) keep (dense_rank first order by sales desc)` will return the `null` from the last row (in the input image), exactly what we don't want it to return. You need to add `nulls last` to the `order by` directive to the `first` aggregate function.

Comment: @charpip - what if the row with sales = 175 also had `null` in the `manager` column? Or is that not possible? If it is possible, the "manager" in the last row will still remain `null`, if we must interpret your explanation strictly. By contrast, in that case, Gordon's first solution would pick the "manager" name from all the rows where the name is `not null` - and from among those, the name with the highest sales. Is that OK?

Comment: I see what you are saying. However, in my case there was no such scenario. If the sales column has a value, then the manager column is not null.